# Search and replace text in a Excel document doesnt work?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to find specific word in excel file in each sheets and trying to replace it with the new word. When I try to run following program it gives me error.

> Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct   The type or
>   namespace name 'DocumentFormat' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?) Error  1   Identifier
>   expected

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;

using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = 
        WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
{




using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
{
    docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
}


SearchAndReplace(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\MyPkg8.docx");

public static void SearchAndReplace(string document)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
    {
        string docText = null;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
        {
            docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Regex regexText = new Regex("Hello world!");
        docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "Hi Everyone!");

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
        {
            sw.Write(docText);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Remove the statement 'using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;'

Comment: I just noticed your code works with a word document and you are asking about excel. Are you looking for an excel version of this word document code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code tested fine

It seems like a dll reference issue (I used `<package id="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" version="2.5" targetFramework="net451" />`)
Or maybe it is the word document itself. I used word 2010.

Try re-adding the package using package manage console `Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml`

Or redownload/add the assemblies directly https://www.nuget.org/packages/documentformat.openxml/

```
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;

    namespace UnitTestProject1
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class UnitTest1
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public void TestMethod1()
            {           
                SearchAndReplace(@"C:\TestDoc\testdoc1.docx");
            }

            public static void SearchAndReplace(string document)
            {
                using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
                {
                    string docText = null;
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
                    {
                        docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    Regex regexText = new Regex("Hello world!");
                    docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "Hi Everyone!");

                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
                    {
                        sw.Write(docText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how can i do this for Excel ?